# Creating standart(copy,cut,paste) buttons qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to implement button ***Edit*** in menuBar with this 3 standart options: cut, copy, paste

[image: like this]

That's my code(using examples from documentation and so on):

```
Action {
    id: _copyAction
    text: qsTr("&Copy")
    shortcut: StandardKey.Copy
    enabled: (!!_mainWindow.activeFocusItem && !! _mainWindow.activeFocusItem["copy"])
    onTriggered: activeFocusItem.copy()
}
```

There are simillar for Cut and Paste and when I wanted to test them i've added simple TextArea object, wrote some text, highlated it and when clicked ***Edit*** button focus have been disappear from text and buttons were disabled .

My question is this possible to make some property of actions(buttons) that will not take focus while clicked on them and does my code for this buttons valid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, I've done this. But I used QTextEdit which has signals for CopyAvailable and PasteAvailable and I made connect from these signals to `action.setEnabled(true)`, try this:

```
connect(ui->m_textEdit, SIGNAL(copyAvailable(bool)), ui->actionCopy, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
connect(ui->m_textEdit, SIGNAL(copyAvailable(bool)), ui->actionCut, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
```

Not sure if it could be made your way and sorry if you needed it exactly your way.

Comment: thanks for help, i've solved problem with focus (there is awesome property focusPolicy), but haven't implemented buttons functionality and i need to implement with qml but if it willn't be possible i try your solution